# % symbol and regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How does this line of code work? Google searches on individual characters don't work well.

```
re.sub(r'(.*>.*/.*)%s(_R[12].*)' % sample.group(1), r'\1%s\2' % sample_name[1], line)
```

What I don't understand:

- `"% sample.group(1)"`     .... what is % doing?
- `'\1%s\2' %`
- `%s`

What I understand:

- re.sub(x,y,z) will substitute x for y in string z
- r is for raw (don't mess with /)
- arrays & indexes
- `_R[12].*` matches "_R" and a 1 or 2 followed by random characters.
- line (it's a string)

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting `%` is the printf style formatting. Basically, it construct regex and replacement string with data from a previous step.

Answer (score 2):

The [`%` string operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) is used for string interpolation/formatting. Think `sprintf` or `String.format`:

```
r'(.*>.*/.*)%s(_R[12].*)' % sample.group(1)
```

Equals

```
r'(.*>.*/.*)' + sample.group(1) + r'(_R[12].*)'
```

Specifically, the `s` operator (i.e., `%s`) is defined as:

> String (converts any Python object using [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)).

[`.format` is the modern way](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) to go, though.